# In kendomobilelistview after scrolling to some extent need to call a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

In a kendomobilelistview I just want to call a function after scrolling to some height. Initially i am loading 20 items and my intention is to load another 20 items So i need to call a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this link will help you http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/endless-scrolling, or you can call on scroll event of the listview

Comment: yahh! this is quite helpfull but. I am expecting some clean explanation